# Is this the real life? Is this just fantasy?

Tags: support, beta-progress

I arrive at my workstation, open Code Review and wait there is something weird on the front page. No more Beta after our site name, well that's strange, let me check my privilege, well I can't close vote anymore and they match a graduated site.

Are we graduated officially or is there a major bug (because Area51 still place us on public beta, and I always thought graduation would be on Monday)? (I would be so happy)

Comment: Caught in a landslide, no escape from reality!

Comment: Open your eyes, look up to the skies and see!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I certainly *hope* it's a bug, because apparently [Programming Puzzles and Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) "graduated" as well, **and that must not happen before we graduate!**

Answer (score 17):

Well it seems like a bug! Thanks to @SimonAndréForsberg that verified other beta sites. It seems like all the beta sites are graduated (YEAH!). See this post for the progress of the bug [Did all sites just graduate?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/236564/did-all-sites-just-graduate)